# Filter posts by custom fields

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I want to give users the ability to sort posts themselves using some filter links on the side, so for instance:

To sort by title: www.example.com/?orderby=title&order=asc

To sort by date: www.example.com/?orderby=date&order=asc

So I want to be able to sort posts using a custom field called "shares" that returns a number , and I use Advanced Custom Fields plugin to generate that field, but not sure how I can generate such query and more importantly, giving a link to apply it if possible.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick web search for 'wordpress sort custom field' returns thousands of results. For something so common you'll want to try on your own first, and then come back here with specific question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I've already tried some stuff like "pre_get_posts" but none of which has talked about how to do that the way I want it, it's all about the query itself and getting the posts to be sorted on page load, not what I want

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple code and after making sure that it works, you need to improve it yourself (adding conditions f.e.)

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','order_post_filter');
function order_post_filter($query){

//then you will need to add some condition here

if (isset($_GET["orderby"]) and isset($_GET["order"])){
$order=$_GET["order"]=='DESC'?'DESC':'ASC';
$query->set('order',$order);
if ($_GET["orderby"]=='date'){
$orderby='date';
}
elseif ($_GET["orderby"]=='title'){
$orderby='title';
}
else {
$query->set('meta_key',$_GET["orderby"]);
$orderby='meta_value';
}
$query->set('orderby',$orderby);
}
}
```

Comment: And how would I allow the users to choose the sort they want? like, the meta_key, what would be the link they click to use that sorting?